# Real analysis question

Tags: real-analysis

I am studing some old exams and came across this one that has me stumped.   Suppose $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is absolutely continuous.   Show

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{2^{n}-1} \left| f( k/2^{n}+1/2^{n} )-f( k/2^{n} )\right|^{2} =0 $$

I can prove this if the derivative of $f$ is bounded but I cannot solve the general case.

Comment: Boy,am I rusty in serious analysis-I couldn't remember how to even begin this problem.I better brush up..........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This result is proved using some extra elementary facts in Theorem 1.10, Page 8, of ["Introduction to Stochastic Calculus with Applications"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/186094129X) by Fima Klebaner.

Every absolutely continuous function is continuous. This one happens to be continuous on a compact set, so also uniformly continuous (although, I think that might be directly implied by the absolute continuity. I can't recall offhand).

Anyway, it's a standard result that any absolutely continuous function $f$ has finite variation, $V_{f} = M < \infty$.

Then the quadratic variation can be written like this:
$$ [f](t) = \lim_{\delta_{n}\to{0}} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\quad \biggl( f(t_{i+1}^{n}) - f(t_{i}^{n})\biggr)^{2} $$
$$ \leq \lim_{\delta_{n}\to{0}} \max_{i}|f(t_{i+1}^{n}) - f(t_{i}^{n})|\cdot{}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\quad |f(t_{i+1}^{n}) - f(t_{i}^{n})|$$
$$\leq \lim_{\delta_{n}\to{0}} \max_{i}|f(t_{i+1}^{n}) - f(t_{i}^{n})|\cdot{} M$$

The last simplification is because the variation is the supremum taken over all partitions of the quantity $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\quad |f(t_{i+1}^{n}) - f(t_{i}^{n})|$.

Now, since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ and thus on $[0,t]$ for any $t\in [0,1]$, the last limit goes to zero:
$$ \lim_{\delta_{n}\to{0}} \max_{i}|f(t_{i+1}^{n}) - f(t_{i}^{n})| = 0. $$

The particular choice of partition in your case involves $k/2$ and $1/2$ raised to the power $n$, but it doesn't matter. The $t_{i}^{n}$ partition points, and the notation $\delta_{n}$ for a $\delta_{n}$-fine partition proves it more generally.

Comment: So we really only needed that f is BV and continuous on a compact set